# In Apache poi XMLSlideShow ppt,how to add sections?

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

I can create a ppt and add pages to the ppt like this:

```
XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow(); // create a ppt
XSLFSlide slide = ppt.createSlide(); // add a new page to ppt
```

but how to add sections to ppt?

and how to add some pages to the section?

Comment: The `Office Open XML` which `apache poi` uses is `Office Open XML` defined in 2006 and first published in `Office 2007`. This `OOXML` does not know something about sections in presentations. Sections were introduced later (2010). So if one would want using that feature, one would must manipulate the XML directly.

Comment: I've updated to ECMA-376 5th edition in [POI 5.0.0](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html), but no-one added the section to the XSLF API as of now. So you need to recreate the sections via the low level XmlBeans, as Axel mentioned. If there are custom Microsoft namespaces used, you might need to use the XmlCursor API of the XmlBeans.

Comment: @kiwiwings thanks, but it's too cumbersome for a feature that is not necessary.